# insert new item in sharepoint list from flex

Tags: apache-flex, sharepoint, caml

i m trying to insert new item on sharepoint list from flex using sharepoint-as3-connector (http://code.google.com/p/sharepoint-as3-connector). but i m getting following error.

```
Response XML:<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
<UpdateListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <UpdateListItemsResult>
    <Results>
      <Result ID="1,UpdateList.NEW">
        <ErrorCode>0x8102000a</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorText>Invalid URL Parameter
```

The URL provided contains an invalid Command or Value. Please check the URL again.

below is the header made in soap URL.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
<UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <listName>
    TestList
  </listName>
  <updates>
    <Batch OnError="Continue">
      <Method ID="1" Cmd="UpdateList.NEW">
        <Field Name="ows_LinkTitle">
          222222
        </Field>
      </Method>
    </Batch>
  </updates>
</UpdateListItems>
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is spot on: you are specifying an invalid command in the `Cmd` attribute of the `Method` element.

Per the [MSDN article for the Method element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459050%28v=office.12%29.aspx), valid values for `Cmd` are:

- Delete
- New
- Update

I have no experience with the "sharepoint-as3-connector", and I suppose it's there to make your life easier. But it's probably worth reviewing the MSDN documentation for the [Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists%28v=office.12%29.aspx) web service (and specifically the [UpdateListItems method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)) so you know what SharePoint is expecting. SharePoint is a delicate flower that cannot be handled harshly; you must know exactly what it wants to keep it happy.

A good walkthrough on MSDN: [How to: Update List Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289%28v=office.12%29.aspx).